# Regex that match all js code but not the commented one

Tags: php, regex

The following regex is supposed to match all js:

- conditional js (OK: already working)
- add js script (OK: already working)
- in line js (OK: already working)
- but not commented Js ( need to be implemented )

**I would like to exclude all js that is commented ( but preserve the one that inside a conditional comment**

Here the current regex:

```
^<!--(\[if lt IE.*?\])>[\s\S]*?<script(\b[^>]*?>)([\s\S]*?)<\/script>[\s\S]*?<!\[endif\]-->$|^<script(\b[^>]*?>)([\s\S]*?)<\/script>$
```

So skip the match for this kind of text:

```
<!--
<script type="text/javascript">
SOME JS
</script> 
-->
```

OR

```
<!--
<script src='...' type="text/javascript"></script> 
-->
```

Conditional comment are usually in this form:

```
<!--[if lt IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
Some JS
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Is it possible to do all the above in one regex ?
Since this is my first regex, if you have any other suggestion is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think is duplicate mine is a very particular question about a particular regex and a particular requirement

Comment: @PaulCrovella This is not a duplicate of that question, and he isn't trying to parse HTML. Finding a sub-string != parsing. This is particularly safe since he's looking for `<script>` tags which cannot be nested.

Comment: @PaulCrovella that could be true for a general parsing, and I'm thankful for your warning, anyway for a particular task could be, also, a false statement ... for ex. `Minify` php use regex to clean the html (https://code.google.com/p/minify/)